# Blender 2.90 - animation keys not showing up

Tags: animation

for some reason, I try to select my animation keys and .... they are gone !!!

they were there, but they magically disappeared

I tried

- dope sheet
- action editor
- shape key editor
- pressing home in the dope sheet

my bones keys are gone

also when I **export to fbx, there is no animations in it, but in blender the full animation plays perfectly**

thanks for helping me on this

[image]

Comment: maybe you've pushed the action down into the NLA, so it is playing but you can't see it in the Dope Sheet, so open the Dope Sheet, switch it to Action Editor and select the action you want to play

Comment: wtf I came back into action (done that many times) and my keys are back ..this gotta be a bug

Comment: now they are all available everywhere, I have been searching 1h30 around this bs...

Comment: ugh wait there is a second animation timeline at the bottom of the screen, here is why..

Comment: ok so some of the bones are showing up (the one I recently added), not the others bones I made an animation for